# XSL-FO whitespaces between elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using this code to make two-level numbering, like "1.1. Chapter One", for example.

```
    <fo:inline>
      <xsl:number from="Book" count="Chapter"/>.
      <xsl:number from="Chapter" count="Chapter"/>.
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="....."/>
    </fo:inline>
```

But I discovered that this code generates the following text:

```
1. 1. Chapter One
```

- with a space between xsl:number elements. And this is what I do not want to happen.
I already have

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

but it does not help anything.

How do I get rid of these parasite spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the periods `.` in `xsl:text` tag

```
<fo:inline>
  <xsl:number from="Book" count="Chapter"/><xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  <xsl:number from="Chapter" count="Chapter"/><xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="....."/>
</fo:inline>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to avoid the new-line outside of the tags as in:

```
<fo:inline>
  <xsl:number from="Book" count="Chapter"/>.<xsl:number
              from="Chapter" count="Chapter"/>.
  <xsl:apply-templates select="....."/>
</fo:inline>
```

And you certainly do not need the `<xsl:text>` since you'll get a newline there. Although if you do not want a newline, again you can remove it like this:

```
<fo:inline>
  <xsl:number from="Book" count="Chapter"/>.<xsl:number
              from="Chapter" count="Chapter"/>. <xsl:apply-templates
              select="....."/>
</fo:inline>
```